# MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json;charset=utf-8

Tags: mule, maven-3, maven-plugin, mulesoft, cloudhub

While deploying my Mule project with Mule runtime 4.3.0 to cloudhub through maven, i am getting below exception:

Execution default-deploy of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5:deploy failed: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json;charset=utf-8, type=class org.mule.tools.client.arm.model.AuthorizationResponse, genericType=class org.mule.tools.client.arm.model.AuthorizationResponse.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks
Vikas

Comment: One addition thing, with JDK 8 it works but not with JDK 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it works with Java 8 indicates it is some Java compatibility issue.

Mule Maven Plugin supports only until Java 11. See the release notes for your version to see software compatibility: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-maven-plugin/mule-maven-plugin-release-notes

Comment: Changing my Mule runtime from 4.3.0 to 4.4.0 (using Java 11), worked like a charm. Thanks.